# CUT command doesn't work in crontab

Tags: shell, awk, cron, cut

I have written shell script to monitor space

```
  echo "___________" `date` "___________"
df | tr -s ' ' $'\t' | cut -f5 > file.txt
echo `sed 's/Use//g' file.txt` > file.txt
echo `sed 's/%//g' file.txt` > file.txt
expression=`cat  file.txt | sed -e 's/ / /g'`
echo $expression
a=($expression)
#echo ${a[0]}
#echo ${a[1]}
#echo ${a[2]}
#echo ${a[3]}
#echo ${a[4]}
#echo ${a[5]}
#echo ${a[6]}
total=`expr ${a[0]} + ${a[1]} + ${a[2]} + ${a[3]} + ${a[4]} + ${a[5]} + ${a[6]}`
echo $total
server=`who`

if [ $total -ge 90 ]
then
    echo "greater"
else
    echo "Space occupied " $total "%"   
fi
```

When I run this script in terminal, it works fine. **tr** and **cut** commands works fine. But when I schedule this script in crontab, tr and cut command doesn't parse output of df command.
Here is output of script when it is terminal

```
1 1 96 0 0 4 1
103
greater
```

output of script when it is scheduled in cron

```
Filesystem$1K-blocks$d$Available$$Mounted$on udev$1945488$4$1945484$1$/dev tmpfs$391332$836$390496$1$/run /dev/sda1$476684304$433659732$18787364$96$/ none$4$0$4$0$/sys/fs/cgroup none$5120$0$5120$0$/run/lock none$1956652$84020$1872632$5$/run/shm none$102400$56$102344$1$/run/user
```

Help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I follow what you are trying to get, but whenever you use crontab you should use the full path to all commands to be used as the path to all may not be available / set.  Your code could be particularly shorter to:

```
echo "___________$(/usr/bin/date)___________"
total=$(/usr/bin/df | /usr/bin/awk 'NR > 1 && NR < 9{s+=$5}END{print s}')

if (( total >= 90 ))
then
  echo "greater"
else
  echo "Space occupied $total%"
fi
```

Comment: It works. Thank you @grail . Full path to commands and `#!/bin/bash` at start of the script works for me.